# comparing date values for equality

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a text box where user enters date in format "YYYY-MM-DD". I have to check whether the entered date is current date as per the server date. If both the date matches then only proceed further. I have to check only the date not date time.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input_text" runat="server" id="englishDate9"/>
```

So how can I check this, is it possible to use asp validator or I have to do it from code behind?

```
#region date check section                
    string sysDt = englishDate9.Value;
    DateTime oDate = DateTime.Parse(sysDt).Date;
    DateTime sysdate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    if(oDate == sysdate)
    {
        // show message
    }
#endregion
```

I am using this code, but I am confused is this the correct code or not although for now it is giving correct result for me?

Comment: what is the format of datetime?

Comment: @viveknuna A DateTime has no format (or it could have many formats depending on how do you transform it in a string).

Comment: Additionally, are you sure you want the time zone of your *server* to be the one that matters for the date comparison? In almost all cases, using `DateTime.Now` in server code is a mistake.

Comment: If you only want to compare dates, use `DateTime.Today`. I suspect you don't need to parse anything either, all date picker controls with a server-side component return a `DateTime` value one way or another. What is `englishDate9` ?

Comment: And most date pickers allow validation by specifying eg a maximum date. If you want to prevent the user from entering `Today` you could set the max date to `DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please check the added code, the user enters the date in text box.

Comment: Suggestion: first, get a copy of LinqPad and try yourself in very short pieces of code. Second, read about unit tests.

Comment: So you use a client-side date picker? They also have validation rules, eg jQuery Datepicker has [maxdate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate). Or can the user enter anything? In any case, if you want to compare just dates on the server side, use `DateTime.Today` for today's date and `DateTime.Date` to get the date part from any other `DateTime` value

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help.

```
DateTime oDate;
                if(DateTime.TryParse(englishDate9.Value, out oDate))
                {
                    if(oDate != DateTime.Today)
                    {                            
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {                      
                    return;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this. because string any be anything thing other than the valid date and the required format.

```
string dateString = "2009-06-20";
DateTime dt;
bool isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
DateTime sysdate = DateTime.Now.Date;
if (isValid == true && DateTime.Now.Date == sysdate)
{
    //Do something
}
```